# Microsoft flow condition to trigger an email when a user selects Yes from a dropdown list in the sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, sharepoint-list, power-automate, if-condition

I am building a microsoft flow to trigger an email when an item is created or modified.I have a field "Mail to be sent" which is a dropdown list - Yes/No in the sharepoint list. I want the mail to be triggered if the user chooses "Yes" and if the user selects "No" then it should not send any email. I tried using condition where the dynamic field "Mail to be sent Value" is equal to "Yes" but still the condition takes as false when the user select Yes and doesn't trigger the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use True/false instead of Yes/No for the if condition part. It works in my end properly.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jerry. It worked! :)